# Spyder plotting blocks console commands

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

Whenever I execute a `plt.show()` in an Ipython console in spyderlib, the console freezes until I close the figure window.  This only occurs in spyderlib and the blocking does occur when I run `ipython --pylab` or run ipython normally and call `plt.ion()` before plotting.  I've tried using `plt.draw()`, but nothing happens with that command.

`plt.ion()` works for ipython, but when I run the same command in spyder it seems to not plot anything altogether (`plt.show()` no longer works).

Enviroment Details:
Python 2.6.5, Qt 4.6.2, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.7.2 on Linux

Comment: which version of spyder and ipython are installed?

Comment: there are problems with ipython >=0.11 in spyder (http://spyder-ide.blogspot.de/2011/09/no-ipython-v011-support-in-spyders.html). I'm using 2.1.9 too and the default console is python with "scientific" startup. If I open a ipython console from within spyder it is one without the --pylab option

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar (I think) problem.  Make sure your interpreter is set to *execute in the current interpreter* (default, should allow for interactive plotting).  If it's set to execute in a new dedicated python interpreter make sure that *interact with the python interpreter after execution* is selected.  This solved the problem for me.